# Maven build: Need edit pom.xml before build

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am a beginner with maven and I'm trying to build [Signal CDS](https://github.com/signalapp/ContactDiscoveryService)
When I run `mvn package` to build, I got error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/t/Documents/ContactDiscoveryService/client/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/contactdiscovery/ContactDiscoveryClient.java:[13,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SignalContactDiscoveryUrl
  location: package org.whispersystems.signalservice.internal.configuration
[ERROR] /home/t/Documents/ContactDiscoveryService/client/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/contactdiscovery/ContactDiscoveryClient.java:[167,5] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SignalContactDiscoveryUrl
  location: class org.whispersystems.contactdiscovery.ContactDiscoveryClient
[ERROR] /home/t/Documents/ContactDiscoveryService/client/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/contactdiscovery/ContactDiscoveryClient.java:[167,57] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SignalContactDiscoveryUrl
  location: class org.whispersystems.contactdiscovery.ContactDiscoveryClient
[ERROR] /home/t/Documents/ContactDiscoveryService/client/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/contactdiscovery/ContactDiscoveryClient.java:[190,42] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRegisteredUsers(java.security.KeyStore,java.util.Set<java.lang.String>,java.lang.String)
  location: variable serviceManager of type org.whispersystems.signalservice.api.SignalServiceAccountManager
```

I got the same error when I use docker to build.

But when I edit top level `pom.xml`, just add a newline or a space, it build success.

Can you guy explain to me why that happen and how to fix it

Thanks

Edit1:
I use maven 3.6.2 and java 11

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T22:06:16+07:00)
Maven home: /home/t/Tools/apache-maven-3.6.2
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-72-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: "when I use docker to build" ... docker isn't a build system so it's not docker that does the building but something else - maybe maven installed inside the container. In any case we'd need to have more information on your build, especially on the poms to provide any meaningful help. With what you provided so far it looks like you're missing some dependencies and/or are using the wrong (or an outdated) pom.xml that get's "updated" somehow when you edit the original.

Comment: Did you check if all the required dependencies are included in your pom.xml?

Comment: I sure all dependencies are include in pom.xml because when I edit it with no mean change (add space at the end and save file), it build ok.

Comment: if this works when you add space or new lines then seems to be the issue of control characters, try dos2unix or unix2dos on pom whichever applicable

Comment: @ankidaemon but when I run `mvn clean` and `mvn package`, that error appear again. I don't why

Comment: Again, if the mvn clean/package is successful when you add a new lines/space then this is the issue of control characters. Seems you are on unix/linux, just run dos2unix pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps worked here

```
$ git clone https://github.com/signalapp/ContactDiscoveryService.git
```

Update a dependency version in `client/pom.xml` from `2.7.8` to `2.9.0`. Because class `SignalContactDiscoveryUrl` was introduced after version `2.8.1`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.whispersystems</groupId>
    <artifactId>signal-service-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

build with

```
$ cd ContactDiscoveryService
$ mvn package
```

Comment: You are right. Version 2.9.0 work well. But it do not answer why that error happen.

Comment: @Programmerdude The version number change solves the problem you posted in the `COMPILATION ERROR` message of your question. For the other problem could you add some steps to reproduce it? Especially what steps you did to get the compilation error. Leaving the version number unchanged result into `Could not find artifact org.whispersystems:signal-service-java:jar:2.7.8` as this version is not in Maven Central https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.whispersystems/signal-service-java

Comment: Yep, version 2.7.8 (in original code) is not exist so I change it to 2.8.1 and that problem happen. Sometime I can build ok but sometime I get error. With no code change, sure

Comment: @Programmerdude Which is surprising, as the missing class was added after version 2.8.1. **1)** `curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/whispersystems/signal-service-java/2.8.1/signal-service-java-2.8.1-sources.jar -o signal-service-java-2.8.1-sources.jar` **2)** `jar tf signal-service-java-2.8.1-sources.jar | grep SignalContactDiscoveryUrl`. Maybe something with your classpath/project settings is garbled.